# How to load data for specific columns from different files for external table in hive

Tags: hive

I have three files and i want to load first 3 columns from first file, next 5 columns from
second file and next 8 Columns from third file.

can someone give me the solution for external table in hive?

Answer (score 0):

Do following step

Load data in three different table.

use row_number() OVER ()  to generate row number for joining tables.

Create view  select required columns from tables.